# How to get the HIGHEST version of an artifact via Maven Nexus REST api?

Tags: maven, nexus, maven-metadata

I though I could use
/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/resolve?r=releases&g=com.mycompany&a=myArtifact&v=LATEST

Then I read about [the difference between LATEST and RELEASE](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/nexus-REST-API-artifact-maven-resolve-redirect-returns-unexpected-for-v-LATEST-td5581415.html).

In Maven 3, LATEST is no longer filled - ok
But RELEASE gives me only the latest released version!
So how can I fetch the HIGHEST version of an artifact?
I need something, which returns version **2.1.3**
Any clue?

Here's my maven-metadata.xml from Nexus:

```
<metadata>
  <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
  <versioning>
    <latest>1.0.4</latest>
    <release>2.0.5</release>
    <versions>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <version>1.0.1</version>
      <version>1.0.2</version>
      <version>1.0.4</version>
      <version>1.0.5</version>
      <version>1.0.6</version>
      <version>1.0.7</version>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
      <version>2.0.1</version>
      <version>2.0.2</version>
      <version>2.0.3</version>
      <version>2.0.4</version>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
      <version>2.1.1</version>
      <version>2.1.2</version>
      <version>2.1.3</version> <!-- released week ago -->
      <version>2.0.5</version> <!-- released today -->
    </versions>
    <lastUpdated>20120531131959</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the code from [DefaultArtifactVersion](http://www.docjar.org/docs/api/org/apache/maven/artifact/versioning/DefaultArtifactVersion.html) to create version instances from the strings which you can sort using `compareTo()`.

The code is in the artifact

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-artifact</artifactId>
  <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Note that this doesn't always work. For example `commons-lang:commons-lang` has the version `20030203.000129` which is older than the latest `2.6` but sorts higher.

Comment: Thanks.
It seems, that this currently only possible programmatically due to the different meaning of LATEST & Co.
Good reading http://blogs.cservenak.com/2011/02/version-or-aversion-from-version.html

Lets see if we get some other definitions in near future to fetch the highest version number...